# css pseudo-classes active don't work if I write hover behind it

Tags: css

If I write hover in front of active, the active's style will work. Just like this

```
    <div class="E">123123</div>

    <style>
        .E {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .E:hover {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .E:active {
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
```

When mouse hover, the div will turn blue, and click it, will turn black color.

The problem is comming. If I change the postion of active and hover.

```
    <style>
        .E:active {
            background-color: black;
        }
        .E:hover {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
```

Whenever I hover or click the div, the color always be the blue.

So why?

Comment: you might need to change :visit color also.

Comment: Because `E:active` and `E:hover` have exactly the same specificity, and therefore the last one wins.

Comment: @kernallora No. First, it's `:visited`, not `:visit`, and second, this is about a div, not a link.

Comment: yup, it's my bad.i missed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Harry and Mr Lister mentioned that both have same specificity so the latest one will win so what you can do is give specific css on active.

So instead of `.E:active` try to `div.E:active` and in this case both will work.

**Updated Code**

```
.E {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        } 
        div.E:active {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .E:hover {
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

Why it will work : As the last option is hover so the background will be blue but we have used specific css(with div) then it will show black color on click too.

See in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/9bj44nmb/1/)